# How to prevent transition on tab change?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, css-transitions

I'm struggling to prevent triggering a transition after switching a tab.

### Example

```js
const { createApp, reactive, ref } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {      
    // switch tabs to see the side effects
    const currentTabIdx = ref(0);

    const listItems = ref([
      [
        { name: 'John', id: 1 },
        { name: 'Joao', id: 2 },
        { name: 'Jean', id: 3 },
        { name: 'Gerard', id: 4 },
      ],
      [
        { name: 'Max', id: 1 },
        { name: 'Moritz', id: 2 },
        { name: 'Foo', id: 3 },
        { name: 'Mo', id: 4 },
      ],
    ])
    
     function shuffleList() {
      listItems.value[currentTabIdx.value] = listItems.value[currentTabIdx.value].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    }
    
    return {
      currentTabIdx,
      listItems,
      shuffleList
    }
  }
});

app.component('list-component', {
  props: ['items'],

  template: `
    <ol>
      <transition-group>
        <li
          v-for="(effect, index) in items"
          :key="effect"
        >
          <div class="header">
            <h5>{{ effect.name }}</h5>
          </div>
        </li>
      </transition-group>
    </ol>
  `,
});

app.mount("#app");
```

```css
li {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.v-enter-active,
.v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.v-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}

.v-enter,
.v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">

  <button @click="currentTabIdx=0">Tab 1</button> <!-- SWITCH TABS TO SEE SIDE EFFECTS -->
  <button @click="currentTabIdx=1">Tab 2</button> <!-- SWITCH TABS TO SEE SIDE EFFECTS -->
  | <button @click="shuffleList">Shuffle</button>

  <list-component :items="listItems[currentTabIdx]"></list-component>
  
  
</div>
```

### Problem

The child component with the list and transition-group triggers side effects on tab navigation.

### Tried

I have tried to disable the transition on the body with `* { transition: none !important; }` but than the list duplicates for a second.

Do you have an idea how to prevent the transition group on tab switch but enable it right afterwards?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand what you want... Are you hoping to instantly hide and have the transition to slowly show the other list?

Comment: let me try to refactor the demo. But for now: I want the list inside the component to be reordered with the transition effect. But the components will be rendered through a tab navigation and the current side effect of removing the old list occurs on tab navigation.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to temporarily combine the two lists and have the same effect currently that shuffle does that will bring your other list into view by transitioning the position of the elements to align 1, 2, 3, ... etc. the the top in their respective slot... Is that what you are trying to do? Because if you just remove the opacity transition you get a near instant change of the elements (out of order) and then a near instant ordering of those same elements... But I'm thinking you want to combine lists reorder and after 0.5 seconds when the other list is invisible remove

Comment: did you see the state of the list between tab changes? I want to remove that effect.

Comment: If you remove `transition: opacity 0.5s;` from your css and do a tab change, you will notice that the transition is gone, but you will notice something more important all the entries are rearranged and then the numbers are assigned... I'm fairly sure you don't want that effect on tab change either (to begin with), so really the problem here is also a data problem, and really you will need to use some js to fix this. You could handle the state upstream and that would make it easier to maintain your transition... But I'm not sure for your use case, or even if that's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to prevent transition on tab change?

Maybe, there's a best way than preventing it.

If you can prefere this, you need to wrap the `list-component` with the `keep-alive` so that that the component is not destroyed and recreated each time the tab changes. As a result, the transition effect is maintained when reordering the list.

```js
const { createApp, reactive, ref, nextTick } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
 setup() { 
 const currentTabIdx = ref(0);

 const listItems = ref([
 [
   { name: 'John', id: 1 },
   { name: 'Joao', id: 2 },
   { name: 'Jean', id: 3 },
   { name: 'Gerard', id: 4 },
 ],
 [
   { name: 'Max', id: 1 },
   { name: 'Moritz', id: 2 },
   { name: 'Foo', id: 3 },
   { name: 'Mo', id: 4 },
 ],
 ])

 function shuffleList() {
 listItems.value[currentTabIdx.value] = listItems.value[currentTabIdx.value].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
 }

 nextTick(() => {
 shuffleList();
 });

 return {
 currentTabIdx,
 listItems,
 shuffleList
 }
 }
});

app.component('list-component', {
 props: ['items'],

 template: `
 <ol>
 <transition-group name="list" tag="ol" mode="out-in">
   <li
     v-for="(effect, index) in items"
     :key="effect.id"
   >
     <div class="header">
       <h5>{{ effect.name }}</h5>
     </div>
   </li>
 </transition-group>
 </ol>
 `,
});

app.mount("#app");
```

```css
li {
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.list-leave-active {
 position: absolute;
}

.list-enter,
.list-leave-to {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
 <button @click="currentTabIdx=0">Tab 1</button>
 <button @click="currentTabIdx=1">Tab 2</button>
 <button @click="shuffleList">Shuffle</button>

 <keep-alive>
 <component :is="'list-component'" :items="listItems[currentTabIdx]"></component>
 </keep-alive>
</div>
```

I use also the `nextTick` here to delay the call to `shuffleList` until the next DOM update cycle so that the `transition-group` applies the transition when the list is rendered.

## Edit

> the transition should stop between tabs, but within the list the transition should be applied.

```js
const { createApp, reactive, ref } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
 setup() {     
   const currentTabIdx = ref(0);
   const listItems = ref([
     [
       { name: 'John', id: 1 },
       { name: 'Joao', id: 2 },
       { name: 'Jean', id: 3 },
       { name: 'Gerard', id: 4 },
     ],
     [
       { name: 'Max', id: 1 },
       { name: 'Moritz', id: 2 },
       { name: 'Foo', id: 3 },
       { name: 'Mo', id: 4 },
     ],
   ])
   
   function shuffleList() {
     listItems.value[currentTabIdx.value] = listItems.value[currentTabIdx.value].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
   }
   
   return {
     currentTabIdx,
     listItems,
     shuffleList
   }
 }
});

app.component('list-component', {
 props: ['items'],
 template: `
   <ol>
     <transition-group>
       <li
         v-for="(effect, index) in items"
         :key="effect"
       >
         <div class="header">
           <h5>{{ effect.name }}</h5>
         </div>
       </li>
     </transition-group>
   </ol>
 `,
});

app.mount("#app");
```

```css
li {
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.v-enter-active,
.v-leave-active {
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.v-leave-active {
 position: absolute;
}

.v-enter,
.v-leave-to {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
 <button @click="currentTabIdx=0">Tab 1</button> <!-- SWITCH TABS TO SEE SIDE EFFECTS -->
 <button @click="currentTabIdx=1">Tab 2</button> <!-- SWITCH TABS TO SEE SIDE EFFECTS -->
 | <button @click="shuffleList">Shuffle</button>

 <list-component v-show="currentTabIdx === 0" :items="listItems[0]"></list-component>
 <list-component v-show="currentTabIdx === 1" :items="listItems[1]"></list-component>
</div>
```

Here, the `v-show` is used to control the visibility of the `list-component`. When the `currentTabIdx` changes, only the `display` of the list component is toggled, and no transition is triggered.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, but even without using `NextTick` the transition occurs on tab change.

Comment: Meaning, you don't want a transition effect when clicking tab1 &| tab2(vice versa) except for shuffle button?

Comment: Yes. As the title and my problem says the transition should stop between tabs, but within the list the transition should be applied.

Comment: I edit the my answer.